# Port 5000 in use constantly

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So, i've just dealt with this. But I need to figure this out I keep getting

> EADDRINUSE :::5000

server.js snippet

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
);
```

If I run command `sudo lsof -i tcp:5000` I get the following:

```
node    16476 jedi   59u  IPv4 0x5494461608a39abb      0t0  TCP localhost:62154->localhost:commplex-main (ESTABLISHED)
node    16499 jedi   12u  IPv6 0x54944615f7c1134b      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
node    16499 jedi   15u  IPv6 0x54944615f724ee0b      0t0  TCP localhost:commplex-main->localhost:62154 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I've dealt with this by killing the node processes every time, but that's annoying. How can I figure out what is causing this conflict? I am running my Node server and React environment concurrently. And I noticed when I run the Node independently I do not get the error. I have a proxy setup in my `package.json`

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

I changed the ports and still get the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: application running on 5000 might by using `forever`, as `forever` restarts an  application if closed. So you need to stop `forever` from stating application. try `forever stop all` this will stop any application using 500. Only if application was started using `forever start`.

Comment: Says no Forever process running =[

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? Been having the same problem after trying a streaming log service.

Comment: I didn't I started programming on my windows machine and stopped having the issue. It really only happens on my Mac.

Comment: Having the same issue, did anyone solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

looks like it's a macOS issue - someone has a solution [here](https://anandtripathi5.medium.com/port-5000-already-in-use-macos-monterey-issue-d86b02edd36c) - TLDR is go into sharing in your system prefereces and uncheck Airplay Receiver, as Airplay receiver is using that port

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick after updating to Monterey

Comment: Thanks @Caitlin. It took my half an hour to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks. Same problem for me (Run a python flask app with docker). I can actually switch to another port, but it was nice to know the root cause :D